# Custom context provider not able to return anything including basic html elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-authentication/?utm_source=reactdigest&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=342) and am up to the part about implementing a custom AuthContext provider. Here is the suggested code:

```js
const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const token = await fakeAuth();

    setToken(token);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setToken(null);
  };

  const value = {
    token,
    onLogin: handleLogin,
    onLogout: handleLogout,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}> // AuthContext defined right above component; initialised as an empty object.
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

As far as I can tell, that's absolutely fine. But when I try adding it to my code (literally copy and paste it in) the return statement throws 9 errors. `Cannot find namespace 'AuthContext'.ts(2503)`, `'>' expected.ts(1005)`, `Operator '<' cannot be applied to types 'boolean' and 'RegExp'.ts(2365)` etc.

Even if I just try to return a `div`, I get `Cannot find name 'div'.ts(2304)`.

What's preventing me from being able to return any elements in my return statement?

EDIT: Update to include my full code.

```js
import React, { createContext, ReactNode, useState } from "react";

type AuthContextType = {
  token: string | undefined;
};

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthContextType>(
  {} as AuthContextType
);

const fakeAuth = () =>
    new Promise((resolve: (arg0: string) => void) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve("2342f2f1d131rf12"), 250);
    });

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: {children: ReactNode}) => {
  const [token, setToken] = useState<string | undefined>();

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const token = await fakeAuth();
    setToken(token);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setToken(undefined);
  };

  const value = {
    token,
    onLogin: handleLogin,
    onLogout: handleLogout,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 11):

Check the file name, in my case it had a .ts extension and it was solved by changing to .tsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, createContext, ReactNode, Context } from 'react';

export type AuthContextType = {
  user?: boolean;
  isLoading?: boolean;
}

export const initialState: AuthContextType = {
  user: false,
  isLoading: true,
};

export interface AuthProviderProps {
  children?: ReactNode
}

export const AuthContext: Context<AuthContextType> = createContext<AuthContextType>(initialState);

const AuthCookieProvider: React.FC<AuthProviderProps> = ({ children }: AuthProviderProps): JSX.Element => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState<AuthContextType>(initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        checkUserLogin(setUser);
    }, []);

    return <AuthContext.Provider value={user}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
};

export default AuthCookieProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you shared the context is created like this before creating the provider

```
const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);
```

If you try something like below?

```
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext(null);

const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [token, setToken] = React.useState(null);

  const handleLogin = async () => {
    const token = await fakeAuth();

    setToken(token);
  };

  const handleLogout = () => {
    setToken(null);
  };

  const value = {
    token,
    onLogin: handleLogin,
    onLogout: handleLogout,
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: I copied your code in and am getting the exact same errors, unfortunately. and the way I initialise should have no impact - that's jsut TS-specific initalisation. And I don't understand what you mean about trying to access the Provider inside the Context. As far as I can tell that's not the case(?)

Comment: Updated above, can you make sure you are creating the AuthContext first?

Comment: I've always been doing that. Updated my questions to include my full code @Gordon